# How can I loop this run every 5 seconds?

Tags: python, loops

I am not a programmer; I just found this code in a youtube video and I just want to spam my friend
Here is the code:

```py
import pyautoguin time
time.sleep(10)
f = open("Noobovi ste", 'r')
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
```

Comment: What do you want to do?

Comment: https://www.fiverr.com/hire/python

If you want the DIY option, I suggest reading some python tutorials

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, it's important to ensure your indentation is correct in the `for` loop.  Not sure if this was just an issue when typing it in here.

To implement the delay, you can use `time.sleep(5)` in your loop just as you did in the beginning to wait 10 seconds before starting it.

```py
import pyautoguin, time
time.sleep(10)
f = open("Noobovi ste", "r")
for word in f:
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(5)
```

This will do whatever you're doing with the gui (I haven't used `pyautogui` before), wait 5 seconds, then do it again.

Comment: Thanks,I'm gonna try it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
import time
import pyautogui
import os
while True:
    os.system("something.txt")
    pyautogui.typewrite(word)
    pyautogui.press("enter")
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: @Daywing I had edited the answer, try this. I think you are trying to do this.

Comment: `os.system` instead of `open`? `word` undefined?

Comment: Because OP is trying to open file, not to open file in python! I know this cuz OP is writing something, we can't write by opening file in python!